Error with SSL cert in spring boot restamplate
I have a web app created with spring boot java. This app is getting data from a server using https ubuntu for the jobs. I used the rest template for connection, but the server has cert ssl, after this I want make the images for exporting to another server for up.
I try much methods but this error not opened :

PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Code:
package dashlet_filter.dashfilter.config;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClients;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.socket.ConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.config.Registry;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.config.RegistryBuilder;
import org.apache.hc.core5.ssl.SSLContexts;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.http.client.support.BasicAuthenticationInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.time.Duration;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() throws Exception {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
        };

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
                .loadTrustMaterial((chain, authType) -> true) 
                .build();
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());

        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                sslContext,
                NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE
        );

        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(
                RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                        .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.INSTANCE)
                        .register("https", sslSocketFactory)
                        .build()
        );


        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                .build();

        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
        requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        requestFactory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5));

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
        
        restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthenticationInterceptor("xxxxxx", "xxxxxx"));

        return restTemplate;
    }
}

